# Set Icon to JApplet titlebar

Tags: java, applet, icons, japplet

I am using `JApplet` embedded in HTML.  How can I set an icon or logo to the title bar of `JApplet`, just like we set icons to `JFrame` using `setIconImage`?

Answer (score 1):

An applet has no title bar, so that is not possible.  You could always try to have the applet set an icon for the web page itself.